# No Gravatar option when editing profile picture, only on Programmers SE

Tags: support, gravatar, profile-picture

First of all, my profile picture on [Programmers SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/52610/janos) has changed *by itself*.
If I recall correctly,
the moment I clicked on the **edit** link,
or when I made a change in one of the fields (not sure),
the picture just changed by itself to what appeared to be **Identicon**.

On other sites, if I try to change my profile picture,
I have **Gravatar** and **Identicon** options.
As far as I can tell,
only on Programmers SE, I don't have a Gravatar option, only Identicon.
I'd like to use Gravatar on this site just like the others.
This was working fine until a few days ago when I made a completely unrelated change to my profile.

Answer (score 3):

The gravatar option is only available when gravatar thinks it has an actual profile picture for your email address. You have a different email address on the programmers profile (changed on Dec 18) vs all the other sites. That email has no profile picture uploaded on gravatar, that's why you can only see an identicon.

Comment: Thanks, I could resolve the problem by updating my email address. I thought using the **Save and copy changes to all Stack Exchange communities** on another site with the correct email address fix it too, but it didn't.